# TrapRoomTile has no attribute trap?

Tags: python, text, adventure

My TrapRoomTile is now throwing an error TrapRoomTile has no attribute trap. I declare self.trap = items.Pitfall() its written exactly how my Enemy tiles are written but I keep getting the error. I imagine I'm overlooking something small like usual so any help would be appreciated

```
import enemies
import npc
import random
import time
import items





class MapTile:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def intro_text(self):
  
    raise NotImplementedError("Create a subclass instead!")

def modify_player(self, player): 
    pass
```

class StartTile(MapTile):
def intro_text(self):
return """
\n You find yourself in a cave with a flickering torch on the wall.
You can make out four paths, each equally as dark and foreboding.
"""
time.sleep(0.5)

```
class EnemyTile(MapTile):
'''            
def __init__(self, x, y):

    r = random.random()
    if r < 0.50:
        self.enemy = enemies.GiantSpider()
        self.alive_text =  "\nA giant spider jumps down from " \
                          "its web in front of you!"
                          
        self.dead_text = "\nThe corpse of a dead spider " \
                         "rots on the ground."
    elif r < 0.80:
        self.enemy = enemies.Ogre()
        self.alive_text = "\n An ogre is blocking your path!"
        self.dead_text = "\nA dead ogre reminds you of your triumph."
    elif r < 0.95:
        self.enemy = enemies.BatColony()
        self.alive_text = "\nYou hear a squeaking noise growing louder" \
                          "...suddenly you are lost in swarm of bats!"
        self.dead_text = "\nDozens of dead bats are scattered on the ground."
    else:
        self.enemy = enemies.RockMonster()
        self.alive_text = "\nYou've disturbed a rock monster " \
                          "from his slumber!"
        self.dead_text = "\nDefeated, the monster has reverted " \
                         "into an ordinary rock."
    
    super().__init__(x, y)
'''
def intro_text(self):
    text = self.alive_text if self.enemy.is_alive() else self.dead_text
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return text

def modify_player(self, player):
    if self.enemy.is_alive():
        player.hp = player.hp - self.enemy.damage
        print("Enemy does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".
              format(self.enemy.damage, player.hp))
    if not self.enemy.is_alive():
        player.gold = player.gold + self.enemy.gold
        if self.enemy.gold == 0:
            pass
        player.exp = player.exp + self.enemy.exp
        total_exp = player.exp
        levels = [0,200,450,1012]
        if True:
            current_level = sum(1 for x in levels if x <= total_exp)
            player.player_lvl = current_level
    
            if not self.enemy.is_alive():
                self.enemy.exp = 0

class GoblinScoutTile(EnemyTile):
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.enemy = enemies.GoblinScout()
    r = random.random()
    if r < .20:
        self.alive_text = "\nA small goblin jumps out at you its not much to look at..."\
                            "Lookout its got a knife!"
    elif r < 50:
        self.alive_text = "\nOut of a dark recess in the wall jumps a goblin"\
                            " ready to scewer you with his dagger"
    else:
        self.alive_text = "\nYou hear a gutteral voice out of the dark "\
                            "walks a goblin ready for battle!"
    self.dead_text = "\nA dead goblin body."

    super().__init__(x, y)

class GoblinBasherTile(EnemyTile):
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.enemy = enemies.GoblinBasher()
    self.alive_text = "\nLookout a Goblin basher and he is looking for a fight."

    self.dead_text = "\n The body of a dead Goblin basher"
    super().__init__(x,y)
```

class VictoryTile(MapTile):
def modify_player(self,player):
player.victory = True

```
def intro_text(self):
    return """
    You see a bright light in the distance...
    ... it grows as you get closer! It's sunlight!
    Victory is yours!
    """


class FindGoldTile(MapTile):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.gold = random.randint(1, 50)
    self.gold_claimed = False
    super().__init__(x, y)

def modify_player(self, player):
    if not self.gold_claimed:
        self.gold_claimed = True
        player.gold = player.gold + self.gold
        print("+{} gold added.".format(self.gold))

def intro_text(self):
    if self.gold_claimed:
        return """
        Another unremarkable part of the cave. You must forge onwards.
        """
    else:
        return """
        Someone dropped some gold. You pick it up.
        """
     
class TrapRoomTile(MapTile):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    r = random.randint(1,2)
    if r == 1:
        self.trap = items.PitFall()

        self.tripped_text = "The open hole of a Pit Fall trap obstructs the tunnel."

        self.set_text = "The floor in this hallway is unusually clean."

    else:
        self.set_text = "Looks like more bare stone... "
    super().__init__(x, y)

def modify_player(self,player):
    if not self.trap.is_tripped():
        player.hp = player.hp - self.items.damage
        print("You stumbled into a trap!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\nTrap does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".
              format(self.items.damage, player.hp))

def intro_text(self):
    text = self.tripped_text if self.trap.is_tripped() else self.set_text
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return text

class EmptyRoomTile(MapTile):
def intro_text(self):
    r = random.random()
    if r < .10:
        return"""
        Rough hewn stone walls are all you can make out in the flickering tourch light.
        """
    elif r < .30:
        return"""
        There is nothing remarkable in this part of the tunnel keep moving onward!
        """
    elif r < .50:
        return"""
        The dirt in this part of th ecave is scuffed but otherise there is nothing
        remarkable here. best push on.
        """
    elif r < 70:
        return"""
        You've been walking for a while without finding anyone or anything.
        no sense in going back now better keep moving.
        """
    else:
        return"""
        Great more stone... Is that a breeze I feel better keep going.
        """



class TraderTile(MapTile):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.trader = npc.Trader()
    super().__init__(x, y)

def check_if_trade(self, player):
    while True:
        print("Would you like to (B)uy, (S)ell, or (Q)uit?")
        user_input = input()
        if user_input in ['Q', 'q']:
            return
        elif user_input in ['B', 'b']:
            print("Here's whats available to buy: ")
            self.trade(buyer=player, seller=self.trader)
        elif user_input in ['S', 's']:
            print("Here's whats available to sell: ")
            self.trade(buyer=self.trader, seller=player)
        else:
            print("Invalid choice!")

def trade(self, buyer, seller):
    for i, item in enumerate(seller.inventory, 1):
        print("{}. {} - {} Gold".format(i, item.name, item.value))
    while True:
        user_input = input("Choose an item or press Q to exit: ")
        if user_input in ['Q', 'q']:
            return
        else:
            try:
                choice = int(user_input)
                to_swap = seller.inventory[choice - 1]
                self.swap(seller, buyer, to_swap)
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid choice!")

def swap(self, seller, buyer, item):
    if item.value > buyer.gold:
        print("That's too expensive")
        return
    seller.inventory.remove(item)
    buyer.inventory.append(item)
    seller.gold = int(seller.gold) + int(item.value)
    buyer.gold = int(buyer.gold) - int(item.value)
    print("Trade complete!")


def intro_text(self):
    return """
    A frail not-quite-human, not-quite-creature squats in the corner
    clinking his gold coins together. He looks willing to trade.
    """
```

world_dsl = """
|EN|EN|VT|EN|EN|
|EN|  |  |  |EN|
|EN|FG|GS|  |TT|
|TT|  |ST|FG|EN|
|FG|  |TR|  |FG|
"""

```
def is_dsl_valid(dsl):
if dsl.count("|ST|") != 1:
    return False
if dsl.count("|VT|") == 0:
    return False
lines = dsl.splitlines()
lines = [l for l in lines if l]
pipe_counts = [line.count("|") for line in lines]
for count in pipe_counts:
    if count != pipe_counts[0]:
        return False

return True

 tile_type_dict = {"VT": VictoryTile,
              "EN": EnemyTile,
              "ST": StartTile,
              "FG": FindGoldTile,
              "TT": TraderTile,
              "GS": GoblinScoutTile,
              "GB": GoblinBasherTile,
              "ER": EmptyRoomTile,
              "TR":TrapRoomTile,
              "  ": None}


world_map = []

start_tile_location = None

def parse_world_dsl():
if not is_dsl_valid(world_dsl):
    raise SyntaxError("DSL is invalid!")

dsl_lines = world_dsl.splitlines()
dsl_lines = [x for x in dsl_lines if x]

for y, dsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
    row = []
    dsl_cells = dsl_row.split("|")
    dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c]
    for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
        tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
        if tile_type == StartTile:
            global start_tile_location
            start_tile_location = x, y
        row.append(tile_type(x, y) if tile_type else None)

    world_map.append(row)


def tile_at(x, y):
if x < 0 or y < 0:
    return None
try:
    return world_map[y][x]
except IndexError:
    return None
```

Comment: You create the trap only sometimes. 50% of the time you don't put that attribute to your TrapRoomTile at all:  `if r == 1: self.trap = items.PitFall()` . You could put `self.trap = None` to the else there, if you really want to have trap tiles without traps.

Answer (score 0):

You create the trap only sometimes. 50% of the time you don't put that attribute to your TrapRoomTile at all:

```
r = random.randint(1,2)
if r == 1:
    self.trap = items.PitFall()
```

You could put `self.trap = None` to the `else` there, if you really want to have trap tiles without traps. Then you need to check if the trap tile has a trap when you try to use it.

It might also be that a component based approach, instead of subclassing, would serve you better, but that's another story.